# Does anybody know what type of WordPress jquery effect this is called? (Pic included)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Does anybody know what this type of thing is called?  Many themes have it, but I'm sure there's a plugin for it.=, but if not, I could find a tutorial  I don't want just a regular jquery slider, or a "carousel" -- unless there's a carousel that does what this does.

Basically, there's a main featured image, with 4 smaller blog excerpts with images to the right.  You click on one of the excerpts, and that becomes the featured image.  So it looks like this:

[image: Jquery Featured on Front Page]

If I can figure out what you call this type of thing, I'm sure I could take things from there.  Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That looks similar to [this](http://www.rvr.ie/datastore/rotator/index.htm)

Comment: Yes, Kei ... that's precisely it.  Thank you for taking the time to respond and provide a link.  I'm going to check out the html output of that and see what I can do ... or just use the builder Michael provided.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript effect you're thinking of are called "sliders." You can check out the source code and design your own here:

http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a bunch, Michael!  I googled this for an hour, and just couldn't seem to figure things out.  Thanks a bunch for taking the time to read my question aqnd respond ... and thanks for the link!